# Different execution time in MariaDB and MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I executed a complex query in MariaDB 10.x and the same in MySQL 5.6 (see SQL below). In MariaDB the execution time was 25 seconds in MySQL 0.01 seconds.

All parameters in my.ini are also identical.

Do you have any clues why there is such a difference?

```
select distinct
resourcety0_.VERSION_ as VERSION1_78_0_,
resourceus1_.ID as ID88_1_,
[... 20 more fields],
case
    when resourceco2_12_.VERSION_ is not null then 12
    when resourceco2_2_.VERSION_ is not null then 2
    [... 20 more cases]
end as clazz_2_
from
BINARY_GUVNOR_RESOURCE_CONTE_0 resourceco2_2_ ON resourceco2_.VERSION_ = resourceco2_2_.VERSION_
    left outer join
DATA_OBJECT_RESOURCE_CONTENT_0 resourceco2_3_ ON resourceco2_.VERSION_ = resourceco2_3_.VERSION_
    left outer join
[... 20 more outer and inner joins]
where
(resourcety0_.RESOURCE_TYPE in ('ARGUMENT1' , 'ARGUMENT2',
    'ARGUMENT3',
    'ARGUMENT4',
    'ARGUMENT5',
    'ARGUMENT6'))
    and resourcety0_.ID = resourceus1_.ID
    and not (exists( select 
        resourcety10_.VERSION_
    from
        RESOURCE_TYPE resourcety10_
            inner join
        VERSION_INFO_TYPE resourcety10_1_ ON resourcety10_.VERSION_ = resourcety10_1_.VERSION_
    where
        resourcety0_.ID = resourcety10_.ID
            and resourcety0_.VERSION_ = resourcety10_1_.PREVIOUS_VERSION))
    and (resourceus1_.OWNER_ID = 'string1'
    or (permission5_.HJVALUE in ('string2' , 'string1'))
    and resourceus1_.OWNER_ID <> 'string1'
    or (permission8_.HJVALUE in ('string2' , 'string1'))
    and resourceus1_.OWNER_ID <> 'string1')
    and resourcety0_1_.DELETED = 0
    and (configurat9_.DTYPE in ('string3'))
order by resourcety0_1_.CREATED ASC
```

Here is the MariaDB EXPLAIN result:

```
id;select_type;table;type;possible_keys;key;key_len;ref;rows;Extra
1;PRIMARY;configurat9_;ALL;PRIMARY; ; ; ;5;Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_4_;ref;PRIMARY,FK9F028B5C42E2A693,FK9F028B5CA7E5C40E;FK9F028B5CA7E5C40E;9;db_data.configurat9_.HJID;1;Using index
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_;eq_ref;PRIMARY;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_5_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKAAE0AD5242E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_6_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK842528CF42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_7_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF5BDD9B6DDDE48DC;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_8_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK415ED7006A929478;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_9_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK561F66796A929478;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_10_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKE6A69C9D42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_11_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK98392DBD65A46193;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_12_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK385C086331440E6;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_13_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKA7D0407442E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourcety0_;ref;PRIMARY,FKF5E4E4CB5B468256,FKF5E4E4CB894B8877,RESOURCE_ID,RESOURCE_TYPE;FKF5E4E4CB5B468256;39;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_14_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF4B8FF842E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_15_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF5C0D3FA42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_16_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKD4B1081342E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using where; Using index
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_17_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF7E6486F42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_18_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK627B607D42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_1_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKA8E578BBDDDE48DC;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_2_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKBFEDBDCB65A46193;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_19_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKE15CF71A42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_20_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKBA3EF7D442E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_21_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKEF28EDEE42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_3_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK545CBF84DDDE48DC;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using index
1;PRIMARY;resourcety0_1_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,VERSION_INFO_DELETED;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourcety0_.VERSION_;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceus1_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,RESOURCE_USAGE_PERMISSION_OWNER_ID;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourcety0_.ID;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;permission3_;ref;FK4D42693835DD5F6E;FK4D42693835DD5F6E;38;db_data.resourcety0_.ID;1;Using where; Distinct
1;PRIMARY;resourceus4_;eq_ref;PRIMARY;PRIMARY;38;db_data.permission3_.CHILD_RESOURCE_USAGE_PERMISS_0;1;Using where; Using index; Distinct
1;PRIMARY;permission5_;ref;PRIMARY,FKFE973D132992B6A5;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceus4_.ID;1;Using where; Distinct
1;PRIMARY;inheritedp6_;ref;FK4D42693935DD5F6E;FK4D42693935DD5F6E;38;db_data.resourcety0_.ID;1;Using where; Distinct
1;PRIMARY;resourceus7_;eq_ref;PRIMARY;PRIMARY;38;db_data.inheritedp6_.CHILD_RESOURCE_USAGE_PERMISS_0;1;Using where; Using index; Distinct
1;PRIMARY;permission8_;ref;PRIMARY,FKFE973D132992B6A5;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceus7_.ID;1;Using where; Distinct
2;MATERIALIZED;resourcety10_1_;range;PRIMARY,VERSION_INFO_PREVIOUS_VERSION,VERSION_INFO_LAST_CHANGED,VERSION_INFO_DELETED,VERSION_INFO_CREATED;VERSION_INFO_PREVIOUS_VERSION;39; ;1;Using where; Using index
2;MATERIALIZED;resourcety10_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF5E4E4CB3F390ABD,FKF5E4E4CB5B468256,FKF5E4E4CB894B8877,RESOURCE_LOCKED,RESOURCE_NAME,RESOURCE_ID,RESOURCE_TYPE;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourcety10_1_.VERSION_;1;Using where
```

And here the MySQL EXPLAIN result:

```
id;select_type;table;type;possible_keys;key;key_len;ref;rows;Extra
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_4_;index;PRIMARY,FK9F028B5C42E2A693,FK9F028B5CA7E5C40E;FK9F028B5CA7E5C40E;9; ;6;Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1;PRIMARY;resourcety0_;ref;PRIMARY,FKF5E4E4CB5B468256,FKF5E4E4CB894B8877,RESOURCE_ID,RESOURCE_TYPE;FKF5E4E4CB5B468256;39;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;configurat9_;eq_ref;PRIMARY;PRIMARY;8;db_data.resourceco2_4_.CONFIGURATION_CONFIGURATION__0;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_;eq_ref;PRIMARY;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_1_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKA8E578BBDDDE48DC;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_2_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKBFEDBDCB65A46193;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceus1_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,RESOURCE_USAGE_PERMISSION_OWNER_ID;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourcety0_.ID;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_3_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK545CBF84DDDE48DC;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using index
1;PRIMARY;permission3_;ref;FK4D42693835DD5F6E;FK4D42693835DD5F6E;38;db_data.resourcety0_.ID;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourcety0_1_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,VERSION_INFO_DELETED;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourcety0_.VERSION_;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceus4_;eq_ref;PRIMARY;PRIMARY;38;db_data.permission3_.CHILD_RESOURCE_USAGE_PERMISS_0;1;Using index
1;PRIMARY;permission5_;ref;PRIMARY,FKFE973D132992B6A5;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceus4_.ID;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;inheritedp6_;ref;FK4D42693935DD5F6E;FK4D42693935DD5F6E;38;db_data.resourcety0_.ID;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceus7_;eq_ref;PRIMARY;PRIMARY;38;db_data.inheritedp6_.CHILD_RESOURCE_USAGE_PERMISS_0;1;Using index
1;PRIMARY;permission8_;ref;PRIMARY,FKFE973D132992B6A5;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceus7_.ID;1;Using where
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_5_;ALL;PRIMARY,FKAAE0AD5242E2A693; ; ; ;1;Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_6_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK842528CF42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_7_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF5BDD9B6DDDE48DC;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_8_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK415ED7006A929478;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_9_;ALL;PRIMARY,FK561F66796A929478; ; ; ;1;Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_10_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKE6A69C9D42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_11_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FK98392DBD65A46193;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_12_;ALL;PRIMARY,FK385C086331440E6; ; ; ;1;Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_13_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKA7D0407442E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_14_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF4B8FF842E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_15_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF5C0D3FA42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_16_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKD4B1081342E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1;Using index
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_17_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF7E6486F42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_18_;ALL;PRIMARY,FK627B607D42E2A693; ; ; ;1;Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_19_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKE15CF71A42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_20_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKBA3EF7D442E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
1;PRIMARY;resourceco2_21_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKEF28EDEE42E2A693;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourceco2_4_.VERSION_;1; 
2;DEPENDENT SUBQUERY;resourcety10_1_;ref;PRIMARY,VERSION_INFO_PREVIOUS_VERSION;VERSION_INFO_PREVIOUS_VERSION;39;db_data.resourcety0_.VERSION_;1;Using index
2;DEPENDENT SUBQUERY;resourcety10_;eq_ref;PRIMARY,FKF5E4E4CB894B8877,RESOURCE_ID;PRIMARY;38;db_data.resourcety10_1_.VERSION_;1;Using where
```

Comment: Please add the result of `explain select...`

Comment: .ini's may be idenditical... but did you check the DB's schemas to make sure the various indexes and actual data are identical?

Comment: I imported the same dump into both databases.

Comment: Add the `explain select...` with MySQL and with MariaDB. It seems that there is some problem with the `configurat9_`table join. Check the indices of this table and show us the inner joins.

Comment: Try to force the same join order in MariaDB than in MySQL. [How to force query plans](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/optimization-and-tuning/query-optimizations/how-to-force-query-plans/)

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and come back with the results.